# Python - Writing to a file stops in the middle

Tags: python, file, numpy

When I try to write to a text file in Python, using `file.write` and `numpy.savetext` Python stops to write in the middle of the text.

I tried closing the file (`file.close`) and reopen it during run-time, it didn't help. I'm pretty clueless.

Comment: Can you provide your code and any error messages you received?

Comment: I don't get any error messages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try closing out Python, close any instances of Python in your task manager, reopen and try again.  Sometimes there are phantom instances... otherwise use Pandas `to_csv` after first converting to a `dataframe`, ie `import pandas as pd,. Dataset = pd.DataFrame(my data), Dataset.to_csv(filename)` This is all from memory not in front of a PC.